# 4 cols fit in 1 row @ width: 47% each

Tags: css

I am having trouble with CSS media queries to set 4 columns to become 2 columns at viewport width 790px or less.

```css
#pl-19 #pgc-19-2-0, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-1, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-2, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-3 {
    width: 22.5%;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 2%;
}
#pg-19-2.panel-no-style {
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.panel-grid.panel-no-style {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-0, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-1, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-2, #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-3 {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 2%;
  }
  #pl-19 #pgc-19-2-3 {
      margin-right: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pl-19">
    <div id="pg-19-2" class="panel-grid panel-no-style">
        <div id="pgc-19-2-0" class="panel-grid-cell">d1</div>
        <div id="pgc-19-2-1" class="panel-grid-cell">d2</div>
        <div id="pgc-19-2-2" class="panel-grid-cell">d3</div>
        <div id="pgc-19-2-3" class="panel-grid-cell">d4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when the viewport width is 780px, I see `pgc-19-2-0`, `pgc-19-2-1`, `pgc-19-2-2`, `pgc-19-2-3` all on the same row - there should be only 2 columns per row at that viewport width, as set by the width: 47%.

Code inspector shows the width of 47% is set properly.

Help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: For 1 you have double quotes `""` in some classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `flex container` to achieve the layout specified. Please try the code below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
    .panel-grid.panel-no-style {
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Also, the CSS for the `.panel-grid.panel-no-style` is wrong. `-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;` is used along with  `flex-wrap: nowrap;`. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
.panel-grid.panel-no-style {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; // this 
    flex-wrap: nowrap; // And this line do the same but have different values
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

For the media query you can change them both to `wrap` in the fist selector or inside the media query set them both to wrap as suggested earlier.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {
    .panel-grid.panel-no-style {
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

As a suggestion based on this HTML snippet I think it is better to use classes instead of id's for all `#pl-19 #pgc-19-2-*`

Answer (score 1):

You have to think like bootstrap framework: working with `min-width` instead of `max-width` you can control better the breakpoint from a big desktop screen to down.

Secondly you are using flexbox in a wrong way: you are set `display: flex` to the parent `.panel-grid.panel-no-style` container but you did not specify the correct `flex` property to it's childs instead you are using `width` property.

You have to choose between flexbox or standard width-display-float way.

If you want standard way this is a correct implementation of your css:

[standard way](https://jsfiddle.net/h2gL7a6t/)

If you want flexboxway this is the way:

[flexbox way](https://jsfiddle.net/79sv6dpc/)

**I've added background-color and height just to see the behavior**